Too many authentication fails Ubuntu
I have been trying to access my VPS via SSH using the SSH key option because with the password does not work, so this is what the error message looks like.
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 1
Received disconnect from 67.38.47.210 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from 67.38.47.210 port 22

I have changed the MaxTries with the same outcome, please help me out.

I am currently using ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and the command I am trying to use is this one ssh -vvv -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey, and if you wonder why I am trying to access my VPS via SSH, first reason is because for some reason the Ubuntu is not recognizing the password, and second, it is more secure to access the vps via Publickey.
It has been almost a month without having one login successfully, I am almost quitting.

I can access my VPS via Remote Desktop connection on Windows, what I am trying to do is to access the VPS via SSH connection.
